# SignedJwtAssertionCredential refresh

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Each thread in my client initializes with

```
self.credentials = oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(...)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = self.credentials.authorize(http)
self.http = http
```

This works fine initially and each client is able do appropriate work.

As the hour approaches and the token nears expiration what is the best way to refresh the credential so that each thread can continue to make progress? I tried

```
self.credentials.refresh(self.http)
```

just before the hour but am seeing

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 355, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 Service Account Access Tokens cannot be refreshed in the same way that regular OAuth  2.0 access tokens are. Instead, you need to [rebuild the credentials from scratch](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#expiration) and request another access token.

So effectively, you would just reuse your initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding threads, please read this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety

There is no need for manual refresh since it's automagically done in the apiclient library ([here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/apiclient/http.py#1026)).

The code should be as follows:

{Shared code}

```
self.credentials = oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(...)
```

.

{Thread code}

```
service = self.credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If refresh is not needed, why does the `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` class have a `refresh` method?

Comment: refresh(self, http): Forces a refresh of the access_token && "The modified http.request method will add authentication headers to each
request and will refresh access_tokens when a 401 is received on a
request" && "Credentials object used for OAuth 2.0 Signed JWT assertion grants. This credential does not require a flow to instantiate because it represents a two legged flow, and therefore has all of the required information to generate and refresh its own access tokens."